# How to get a single dotted line in genealogytree?

Tags: tikz-pgf, genealogytree

EDIT: I found another solution: `family={edges={foreground={line width=1pt,dotted},background=white}}`, which is necessary for more than one child.

---

In a genealogical tree I need single dotted line, namely (in my example) from Levi to Moses,  indicating that Moses is not the immediate offspring, but just a descendant.

PS: Why does the line between Rahel and Jakob has its starting point the right side under the Jakob-box though Rahel is on the left side?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border={20pt 20pt 20pt 20pt}]{standalone}
\PassOptionsToPackage{many,poster}{tcolorbox} % loaded by
                                % genealogytree
\usepackage[main=ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage{luatextra}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \genealogytree[template=signpost,%
  box={natural height,fit, no shadow}]
  {
    child[id=fam_A]{
      g[id=na1,male,pivot]{Abraham}
      p[id=na2,female]{Sarah}
      child[id=fam_B]{
        g[id=nb2,male,pivot]{Isaak}
        c[id=nb3,male]{Esau}
        p[id=nb1,female]{Rebekka}
        child[id=fam_C]
        {union[id=fam_D]
          {
            p[id=nd1,female]{Rahel}
            c[id=nd2,male]{Josef}
          }
          child[id=fam_D,%
                   family={edges={foreground={line %<---
                   width=1pt,dotted},background=white}}%<---
                ]
            {
            g[id=nd1,male,pivot]{Levi} 
            c[id=nd2,male,pivot]{Moses} 
            c[id=nf3,male]{Aron}
            }
          c[id=nc1,male]{Ruben}
          g[id=nc2,male,pivot]{Jakob}
          p[id=nc3,female]{Lea}
        }
      }
    }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: from Abraham to Moses]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you use the id option, you can use the name to refer to nodes and do what you will with them after the tree is completed.

For example, using id=nd1 and id=nd2, we can add the line

```
\draw [white, line width=2pt, dashed] (nd1) to (nd2);
```

to produce the dashed line

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border={20pt 20pt 20pt 20pt}]{standalone}
\PassOptionsToPackage{many,poster}{tcolorbox} % loaded by
                                % genealogytree
\usepackage[main=ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
% \usepackage{luatextra}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \genealogytree[template=signpost,%
  box={natural height,fit, no shadow}]
  {%
    child[id=fam_A]{%
      g[id=na1,male,pivot]{Abraham}
      p[id=na2,female]{Sarah}
      child[id=fam_B]{%
        g[id=nb2,male,pivot]{Isaak}
        c[id=nb3,male]{Esau}
        p[id=nb1,female]{Rebekka}
        child[id=fam_C]
        {union[id=fam_D]
          {%
            p[id=nd1,female]{Rahel}
            c[id=nd2,male,pivot]{Josef}
          }%
          child[id=fam_D]{%
            g[id=nd1,male,pivot]{Levi} % <-- !!!!!!!!
            c[id=nd2,male,pivot]{Moses} % <-- !!!!!!!
          }%
          c[id=nc1,male]{Ruben}
          g[id=nc2,male,pivot]{Jakob}
          p[id=nc3,female]{Lea}
        }
      }
    }
  }
\draw [white, line width=2pt, dashed] (nd1) to (nd2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```